# What is a better word for "works with" or "supplements"?

Tags: vocabulary

*Situation:* A device does not require other special devices but works with standard equipment (and requires it to function properly). It is more that the device supplements the other devices.

I am now looking for a different way to express something like this:

> ... and does therefore **work with** standard equipment.

Is there any better word for this?

Comment: Is the device a _peripheral_ device or a _standalone_ device? Please elaborate on the situation with an analogy.

Comment: It's a peripheral device. Think of a ultrasonography device: the other device is attached to it and uses the images it generates. I'd like to express that this does not require you to have a special type of ultrasonography device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terms like *[complement](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/complement#Verb)*, *[enhance](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enhance#Verb)*, and *[augment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/augment#Verb)* are often used in such a context.  A common sense of *to complement* is "To complete, to bring to perfection, to make whole. [eg] We believe your addition will complement the team."  Wiktionary also shows a sense close to what you seek:  "To provide what the partner lacks and lack what the partner provides. [eg] I believe our talents really complement each other."

*Edit:* Indicating that your device works with a broad range of equipment is likely to require additional terms that specify what kind of equipment your device connects to (or, as coleopterist phrased it, *plugs into* or *integrates with*.  For example, "This video printer complements / enhances / integrates with / is compatible with / connects to / plugs into / works with / attaches to / augments any ultrasound machine that supports XVGA output."

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Can you maybe also give your opinion about this: I'm trying to put the focus on the fact that no special equipment is required rather than on the "supplementing" feature, and I'm not quite sure whether "complement" expresses that very well?

Comment: I suggest saying that in a separate sentence or phrase, along lines of "Any standard ABC cable suffices to connect the PQR to your ultrasound's XVGA output" or "Attach the PQR to your ultrasound equipment in moments using standard ABC cables."

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something along the lines of:

> ... and can be *easily plugged into* standard equipment.

(Depending on the industry, *plug'n'play* might also be an option)

or

> ... and does therefore *integrate with* standard equipment.

or

> ... and can be *easily integrated with* standard equipment.